Facebook doesn't receive events (Flutter, android, facebook_app_events)
I use facebook_app_events 0.19.2 in my app.
In the iOS application everything works well, but in Android I don’t see events in the Facebook event manager.
I followed all the setup recommendations from here. https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events
I have a separate application in the Facebook console for Android, and in the advanced settings they tell me to update the version:

As far as I understand, the library facebook_app_events should contain the latest Facebook SDK.
So what can I do? Perhaps I will have to add a native implementation of the Facebook SDK for the Android version?

What's preventing you from upgrading to 13.0.0?

@LawrenceGimenez This was partly what my question was about. I'm using a flutter library, which should include the latest SDK (and this works in the case of iOS). If Facebook does not see events, should I then try to integrate the native Android Facebook SDK in my flutter app?

Yeah why not try upgrading everything and see how it goes.
